# How to show convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\log(1 + \frac{1}n)$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to prove whether 
\begin{equation*}
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\log(1 + \frac{1}n) 
\end{equation*}
converges or diverges, but none of the normal tests (nth test, p test, etc. ) seem to work.

I was just wondering if someone wouldnt mind giving me a suggestion as to how i would show if this converges or diverges?

Thanks in advance
C :)

Comment: Hint: it equals $\sum\ln(\frac{n+1}n)$

Comment: Hint 2: $\sum{ln} = ln{\prod}$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [study the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log \frac{n+1}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148075/study-the-convergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-log-fracn1n)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\log(1 + \frac{1}{n})} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\log(\frac{n + 1}{n})} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left(\log(n + 1) - \log(n)\right)} = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}{\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}{{\left(\log(n + 1) - \log(n)\right)}}\right)} = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}{\log(N + 1)} \rightarrow \infty$$

Therefore,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\log(1 + \frac{1}{n})}$$ diverges.

Comment: Hey, thanks heaps for that, it is much appreciated. However I dont understand how you got to the last part (one involving $N$). What happened to the $-ln(n)$? Sorry about all this. Thanks again, Corey

Comment: @Fishingfon (Corey): Here's your hint - look up [telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Comment: @Fishingfon, here's your hint #2 - $\log 1 = 0$.  =)

Comment: Thanks heaps, i got it now :). Corey

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help!

Answer (score 6):

for positive sequences, if $a_n \sim b_n$, then $\sum a_n $ converges $\iff \sum b_n$ converges

Since $\log(1 + \frac 1n) \sim \frac 1n$ and the latter diverges, we conclude that

$$\sum \log\left(1 + \frac 1n\right)$$ diverges, too

Comment: Where $a_n \sim b_n$ means that there is $c>0$ with $\frac{1}{c} a_n \leq b_n \leq c a_n$ for large enough $n$.

Comment: And where one assumes positivity.

Comment: @Did Right! Edited :)

Comment: @LeBtz Yes! or $\lim \frac{a_n}{b_n} = c \neq 0$ :)

Answer (score 1):

$\sum \ln(1+\frac{1}{n})=\sum \ln(\frac{n+1}{n})=\ln\Pi_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+1}{n}=\ln(1\frac21\frac32...\frac{n+1}{n}\frac{n+2}{n+1}...)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\ln(n)=\infty$

Answer (score 1):

It is well-known that the harmonic sequence $H_N=\sum_{k=1}^N \frac1k$ diverges to infinity. And, for $N\in\Bbb N$,

$$\sum_{n=1}^N\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)=\sum_{k=1}^N\int_1^{1+\frac1n}\frac{dx}x\ge\sum_{k=1}^N\frac1n\cdot\frac{n}{n+1}=H_N-1$$